# Alternative to functions inside Angular Template

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have a very common instance of an issue all over my app.  I'll give a simple example.

component code:

```
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let selectedItems = [2, 4];

public isSelected(item: number): boolean {
    return this.items.find(x => x === item) != null;
}
```

template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <span class="check-mark" *ngIf="isSelected(item)"></span>
    {{ item }}
</div>
```

I'm well aware that this is bad practice:

```
*ngIf="isSelected(item)"
```

I am also aware that two solutions to this issue is
1.  Use pipes
2.  Store values in local variables

I do not have the option of doing either because my "items" and "selectedItems" are populated via data calls and I have varying object types as well.  They are not static arrays.

It would be nice if Angular had an "ngIfChange" directive that only executed if a specified object changes.  Something along the lines of this:

```
*ngIf="isSelected(item); change selectedItems"
```

Does anyone know of a clean, simple way of handling arrays/lists/objects like this without the "functions in templates" issue?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend: `return this.items.indexOf(item) >= 0;`. A better alternative, if possible, is to turn each item into an object: `items = [{ value: 1, selected: false }, { value: 2, selected: true }, ...]` instead of having the selected items in a separate array.

Comment: My example is just that - an example.  Your suggestion has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: His given alternative  IS the way to solve this though..

Comment: the correct way to handle this is the way others have shown.  even if your data is coming from an api, you don't need to stick with just that data structure. you map it into a more friendly view model to work with.

Comment: Before he edited, he only posted this:   I would recommend: return this.items.indexOf(item) >= 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To eliminate calling a function in your template, I would recommend creating a structure as follows:

```
items = [
  { value: 1, selected: false },
  { value: 2, selected: false },
  { value: 3, selected: false }, 
  // ...
];
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <span class="check-mark" *ngIf="item.selected"></span>
    {{ item.value }}
</div>
```

Comment: I have used this method, however, it is slightly inconvenient because and not as passive.  For example, in your solution, "items" is the object I would be working on, but "selectedItems" is the object I need to save to the database.  So either I have to keep both objects updated at all times OR prepare selectedItems when the user clicks save.

Comment: Also, I don't delete data from my database, I just set an IsDeleted flag on all of my tables.  So the logic behind keeping track of these changes gets to be kind of hairy.  But I do understand that this is a "best" solution that I've ever come across.  I was just curious if there were any other ways.

Comment: Definitely do not keep two objects updated, IMO that is just asking for trouble. Keep a single point of truth. It's very simple to only get the selected values on save: `const selectedItems = this.items.filter(item => item.selected).map(item => item.value);`

Comment: @SamHerrmann - In your example, make sure to use `items = ...` instead of `items: ...`, so that nobody gets bitten by this mistake which is not always easy to detect.

Comment: Good catch @ConnorsFan! I fixed my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a great idea, and you can't do it exactly like you're imagining due to how template expressions are evaluated, but nothing is stopping you from writing a structural directive like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myIf]'
})
export class MyIfChanged {
  @Input('myIf') conditional

  @Input('myIfParams') params = []

  @Input() set myIfChanged(value) {
    this.viewContainer.clear()
    if (this.conditional && this.conditional(...this.params)) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef)
    }
  }

  constructor(private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}
```

which could be used like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <button (click)="change()">change</button>
    <div *myIf="isSelected; params [1]; changed selected">SHOW</div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  selected = []
  isSelected = (value) => this.selected.indexOf(value) > -1
  change() {
    this.selected = [1]
  }
}
```

it's weird, but it works. structured the params as an array to allow multiple parameters. you need to define the function passed in as an arrow function and you need to never mutate the variable to be watching. but this would work fine under those hidden dependencies.

sample blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ktq4re?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Having `selectedItems` as Dictionary solves the problem

```
public items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
public selectedItems = {
  2: true,
  3: true,
};

// example toggle selection function
toggleSelection(item) {
  this.selectedItems[item] = !this.selectedItems[item];
}

// example on submit logic
onSubmit() {
  const selectedItemsToSend = Object.entries(selectedItems)
                                    .filter(([item, selected]) => selected)
                                    .map(([item, selected]) => item);
  // rest of ur logic
}
```

template:

`<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <span class="check-mark" *ngIf="selectedItems[item]"></span>
    {{ item }}
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest a better solution if I understand the problem better.

But from what I can see in your current description, a nice and simple way to avoid unnecessary computation is to just memorize it.

There are a lot of similar libraries help you do that, such as [memoizee](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoizee)

And your code becomes

```
public isSelected = memoizee(oldIsSelected);
```

Another way that probably makes more sense, but needs a better context, is to manually control when to compute this "selected items" list. Have event triggers and listeners (perhaps just rxjs observables), and have your Angular template simply subscribe to this observable using `async` pipe.